# How to fix ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack?

Tags: python, database

I get the following error when using the below query,am already giving variables when doing cursor.fetchall ,not sure
why am I getting this error,how to overcome this?

Query:-

```
query = """SELECT metabuild,testbed FROM gerrits.pw WHERE warehouse ='%s'"""%(warehouse_name)
rows  = cursor.execute(query)
(metaBuild,testbed)= cursor.fetchall()
```

Error:-

```
    (metaBuild,testbed)= cursor.fetchall()
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchall` returns a list of tuples, one tuple per row. If you are certain that your query returns just one row, do

```py
(metaBuild,testbed)= cursor.fetchall()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `fetchone()`:

```
metaBuild, testbed = cursor.fetchone()
```

Also, don't make your query via string formatting or interpolation - this way you are making your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Instead, "parameterize" the query:

```
query = """
    SELECT 
        metabuild, testbed 
    FROM 
        gerrits.pw 
    WHERE
        warehouse = %s
"""
cursor.execute(query, (warehouse_name, ))
```